# How do I find out the host for the local SQL 2005 server?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am connected to my company's SQL 2005 server over LAN.

How do I find out the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `select host_name()`?

Answer (score 2):

In command prompt type in

```
netstat -a
```

This should give you the list of all current TCP connections. You should be able to see the one connected to a server on the mssql port.

Comment: netstat -a runs very fast and the command closes within 1 sec. How could I keep it open?

Answer (score 1):

Start -> Run

then type:

```
cmd
```

in a command window type:

```
netstat -o -a
```

Then switch to taskmanager and find PID of your application, so you can then search this pid in netstat output. I think there will be enough details for you.

Comment: netstat -o -a runs very fast and the command closes within 1 sec. How could I keep it open?

Comment: Either run it from a command prompt or use cmd /k netstat -o -a

Comment: start -> Execute -> cmd
Then write netstat there and the window will not close.

Comment: @Greg - use Jonathan  or adrianbanks approach. I am also adding this to my reply.